# Rotating a line to look at the mouse with linear interpolation causes jumping

Tags: javascript, geometry, p5.js, lerp

Earlier, I was trying to find out how to rotate a line around a pivot using p5.js, and I played with the code a little bit to make the line point towards the mouse using the `atan2` function. It worked fine, and I decided to see what it would look like if I used linear interpolation (`lerp`) to make the animation look smoother. What was weird is that it seemed once the line passed a certain point, it jumped to the other side instead of just moving to that point.
[image: example image of issue]

Here's the code I'm having the issue with:

```
let angle = 0;

let rot = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
}

function draw() {
  let v1 = createVector(width / 2 - 50, height / 2);
  let v2 = createVector(width / 2 + 50, height / 2);

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);

  rot = lerp(rot, atan2(mouseY - v1.y, mouseX - v1.x), 0.1);

  push();
  translate(v1.x, v1.y);
  rotate(rot);
  translate(-v1.x, -v1.y);
  let r0 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  strokeWeight(10);
  let p1 = point(v1.x, v1.y);
  let p2 = point(v2.x, v2.y);
  pop();
}
```

How can I make this animation look smooth, without the weird jumping?

Comment: Good question. Not specific to p5, but there's also [Rotate an object gradually to face a point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821013/rotate-an-object-gradually-to-face-a-point/73423832#73423832)--most of the issues are math rather than the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `atan2` returns value between `-Math.PI` to `+Math.PI` so there is a jump where the linear interpolation fails for the expression `target_angle = atan2(mouseY - v1.y, mouseX - v1.x)`.

That's why, in order to make the shortest path between current `rot` to `target_angle` we should normalize the difference between so that the distance to cover its `abs` value should be less than `Math.PI` (half a circle)

```js
let angle = 0;

let rot = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
}

function draw() {
  let v1 = createVector(width / 2 - 50, height / 2);
  let v2 = createVector(width / 2 + 50, height / 2);

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);


  let target = atan2(mouseY - v1.y, mouseX - v1.x);

  while (target - rot > Math.PI) {
    target -= 2 * Math.PI;
  }

  while (target - rot < -Math.PI) {
    target += 2 * Math.PI;
  }

  rot = lerp(rot, target, 0.1);

  push();
  translate(v1.x, v1.y);
  rotate(rot);
  translate(-v1.x, -v1.y);
  let r0 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  strokeWeight(10);
  let p1 = point(v1.x, v1.y);
  let p2 = point(v2.x, v2.y);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.9.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very good answer, but I have another question: right now, the only indication of the rotation is a point, being physically rotated using `rotate`. How can I get the position of that point after its rotation using math? Sorry if this a dumb question

Comment: one method: you got the angle and you got the radius so you can calculate. use `x = Math.sin(rot) * radius` and `y = Math.cos(rot) * radius`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on IT goldman's nice answer(+1) with the same principle @ggorlen metioned. (I was familiar with the idea from actionscript 3 days from [GreenSock's ShortRotationPlugin](https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-AS3/blob/master/src/com/greensock/plugins/ShortRotationPlugin.as)). Credits go to them.

This is the mixture of the above: the key difference is avoiding the blocking `while` loops (which I don't generally recommend).

```js
let angle = 0;

let rot = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
}

function draw() {
  let v1 = createVector(width / 2 - 50, height / 2);
  let v2 = createVector(width / 2 + 50, height / 2);

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(4);


  let target = atan2(mouseY - v1.y, mouseX - v1.x);
  // check remainder wrt to full 360 degrees (2 * PI)
  let diff = (target - rot) % TWO_PI;
  // if the difference is not on this half of the circle (needs short rotation) wrap around the circle (add or remove 2*PI) depending on the sign of the difference
  if (diff != diff % PI) {
    diff = (diff < 0) ? diff + TWO_PI : diff - TWO_PI;
  }
  // ease towards the rotation using short rotation angle difference
  rot = lerp(rot, rot + diff, 0.1);

  push();
  translate(v1.x, v1.y);
  rotate(rot);
  translate(-v1.x, -v1.y);
  let r0 = line(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x, v2.y);
  strokeWeight(10);
  let p1 = point(v1.x, v1.y);
  let p2 = point(v2.x, v2.y);
  pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```